# Foreach with two arrays in a Makefile

Tags: makefile

I have to dynamically build rules in a Makefile from two arrays:

- A file suffix
- A generation code

I found the following syntax on SO, but unfortunately it doesn't work

```
$(foreach (a,b), ($(arrayA),$arrayB), $(eval $(call BUILD_RULES,$(a),$(b))))
```

Instead I found this solution which involve a third variable to iterate trough my arrays:

```
ITERATE =    1    2    3
EXT     = _FOO _BAR _QUX
CODE    =   34   33   36

define BUILD_RULES
dir/file_a$(word $1, $(EXT)).h:
    genfile -a $(word $1, $(CODE)) > $$@

dir/file_b$(word $1, $(EXT)).h:
    genfile -b $(word $1, $(CODE)) > $$@
endef

$(foreach i, $(ITERATE), $(eval $(call BUILD_RULES,$(i))))
```

Is there a better way to write this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I don't know if it's better or not, but you could alternatively do something like this:

```
# Initial values
EXT     := _FOO _BAR _QUX
CODE    :=   34   33   36

# Getters
JOINED  := $(join $(addsuffix :,$(EXT)),$(CODE))
GET_EXT  = $(word 1,$(subst :, ,$1))
GET_CODE = $(word 2,$(subst :, ,$1))

define BUILD_RULES
dir/file_a$1.h:
    genfile -a $1 > $$@

dir/file_b$1.h:
    genfile -b $2 > $$@
endef

$(foreach j,$(JOINED),$(eval $(call BUILD_RULES,$(call GET_EXT,$j),$(call GET_CODE,$j))))
```

Comment: Actually I think `$(split` doesn't work with GNU Make 4.0. I get an empty value with `$(error $(split :,$(JOINED)))`

Comment: Sorry, I messed up.  Not sure what I was thinking.  Try the above.